# Returning data to connected client upon SQL UPDATE

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am looking for a way to monitor the data in an SQL database without spamming requests to check the data every one sec. I need some sort of "SQL update request" trigger that will allow my PHP web server to establish a connection to the SQL server and wait until the SQL server returns a response triggered by another client updating the table data. As far as I can see this is not something one can simply do with SQL triggers, since a trigger can not return data.

I am using google cloud SQL and google cloud Linux VM for the server. The idea is to create a REST API with the PHP server so that the system can be easily implemented on all platforms with a simple http.get("") method.

Comment: look into using websockets and whenever your server side code updates sql can push data to client. Is far less server load than long polling with ajax and virtually real time

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? If it's SQL Server by any chance you could use a service broker queue to wait on.